# App crashing "due to uncaught exception"

Tags: objective-c

My app always crashes and goes to the main.m file. It shows the following error in the output:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error implies that there is the function `initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` being called on a NSURL with a parameter being `nil`. Check your parameters that call this function and make sure they're not nil.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This mean that `[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]` nil so it crash.
You should put breakpoint and run again to find where is it crash. You can see image below:

[image]